# Braintree iOS v4 SDK sandbox is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, braintree

Previously I was using Braintree iOS v3 SDK but it seems not working anymore so I have changed to iOS v4 SDK.

[image]

The issue that I am facing here is when I click any of the buttons, there is no response at all. What might be the problem? Did I miss out something in the setup? I have followed the exact same steps provided by Braintree.

The link of docs: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4#present-drop-in-ui

My code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
    self.clientToken = @"token"; //token
}

- (void)showDropIn:(NSString *)clientTokenOrTokenizationKey {
BTDropInRequest *request = [[BTDropInRequest alloc] init];
BTDropInController *dropIn = [[BTDropInController alloc] initWithAuthorization:clientTokenOrTokenizationKey request:request handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
    } else if (result.cancelled) {
        NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        result.paymentOptionType = BTUIKPaymentOptionTypePayPal;
    }
}];
    [self presentViewController:dropIn animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)callBrainTree:(id)sender
{
    [self showDropIn:self.clientToken];
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: hey I am working on app using Braintree API also, i think I could help. But first or all, can you post your code out first, otherwise we can help you :p

Comment: Code is posted. thanks

Comment: You code looks fine, is there any debug message @ XCode console? Add a breakpoint, check if the shopDropIn function is called?

Comment: Yes the function is called because I have the dropIn will show and I can select the options(PayPal, credit card) inside. Just that when I select PayPal it directs me to the page (image above) and I couldn't proceed since the buttons are not responding.

Comment: Oh for my app, the purchase action is performed on the server side, so I can help you on this. I think you should change the question headline to specify "Braintree sandbox purchase".

Comment: Can you show me your way of integrating Braintree to your app?

Comment: For my use case, I do the card tokenization (Braintree provides) on the client side(app). Then I send the token to server, so that the server can use the card info to charge our users anytime we want. While if this process is done on client side, we cant guarantee it.

Comment: i also had the same problem are you able to solve it till now

Comment: Are you using the latest braintree? if so please try braintree version 3.9.3 instead of the latest one, see if this works. Another reason might be the token is not generated properly

Comment: Can I send amount in BTDropInRequest?